How do I convert keyframe animations to a fbx file?
I'm an absolute beginner to Blender and I'm working on animating this horse's skeletal foot with all its ligaments. To animate the foot itself, I've put an armature on it and put in keyframes for animation

Since I wanted the ligaments to be "stretchy" I put a cube "around" them and a mesh deform modifier on the ligaments itself. I've hooked the caging cube to hooks. I have basically followed this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ihW4myc7Fko tutorial step by step.

My problem now is when I try to convert it to .fbx (to upload it on sketchfab) some objects have no animation at all and some do.
I've bascially put keyframes on the objects, the armature, the hooks and the cubes for the mesh deform modifier; it's pretty messy tbh but since this is my first project ever I'm sort of lost.
Help is appreciated and I'm sorry for not really using tech language. Not really the best at operating computers lol

And you followed the correct steps of how to export to .fbx?

When it comes to exporting animation, there are two routes you can go: standard or mesh cache.
Standard is what most exchange formats and softwares will support: shapekeys and transforms keyframes on objects or bones deformations. Anything else like physics simulations, geonodes or modifiers deformations is pretty much to be considered off limits.
Here you are having issues precisely because you are trying to make a standard export while using non-standard technologies to animate.
Standard exchange formats are your everyday FBX, OBJ, gLTF, etc...
Mesh cache is something that comes from the VFX industry AFAIK. Instead of exporting mesh objects and bones with keyframes and let the target software evaluate the animation on the fly like standard export does, you take snapshots of the mesh "as it is".
The advantage being that it doesn't matter how you deformed the mesh, since it's a snapshot of the results that is exported, and there's nothing to evaluate in the target software, so you not only are sure to have exactly the same result, but at a lower performance cost.
But the downsides are that these formats are not supported everywhere, are heavy, and are meant to be a final export, you can't really do modifications on the exported data, since there are no bones and keyframes animating a mesh: it really is just a bunch of snapshots of your mesh for each frame.
Such formats are Alembic and USD.
Since you are exporting to Sketchfab, Alembic and USD are available to you, so you could export your animation as-is using Alembic. But if your goal is to let the user download your model and customize the animation, these formats will not allow that.
You could use standard export formats, but it would mean first refactoring your animation system to use only bones and shapekeys so that it can be supported.

Thank you so much for your response! I now understand my problem much better and I will definitely have an in depth look into shape key animation!

My pleasure. If that answer was useful. please hit the ✔️ and ⬆️ buttons to the top left corner of my answer to give it more visibility and send the proper rewards ;)
